# Is there any option validate form from controller not models in cakephp3.8

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to validate on server my form from controller without models 
Please anyone help me

this is code

[image]

Comment: First, you'll get better responses if you include the code directly here (with appropriate formatting) instead of as a screen shot. People can copy-and-paste code, and edit it to make suggestions. Nobody is going to re-type your code to show what you should do.

Comment: That said, you clearly have a model that you're using to save the data. What's the problem with using it for validation?